# My USB pendrive always goes read-only, what can I do?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, read-only

I have a transcend 16 Gb usb pendrive. I save my daily works to it. I wrote a bash script to copy the contents of my working directories to the pendrive. The bash script contains only "cp" and "mkdir" command, and one call to "rar" archiver, nothing else. The pendrive is automatically mounted at boot. When I copy files to it with Midnight Commander, the copying goes right, I also can make directories etc. However when I run my bash script it can't write to the disk and it becomes read-only. Then I am unable to make directories, copy files etc. What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Attrib" command in your script to remove read only instantly.